# Access tweets under free tier?

Tags: twitter, oauth, postman, information-retrieval

I am  new to the X developer platform. My question is under free tier can I access tweets under free tier?

I read the documentation and I am pretty sure that the answer is no but in the picture below from the developer platform it says that 0 of 1500 tweets pulled. What does this mean?

[image]

Secondly, I have a use case wherein I need to pull tweets from last year for a month or so for few users (it shouldn’t be more than 10). Can I accomplish this by upgrading to basic tier?